# Visual Studio Command Prompt vs. a regular command prompt?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, command-prompt

When I open a Visual Studio command prompt (for example, opened with menu *Start* -> *Programs* -> *Microsoft Visual Studio 2008* -> *Visual Studio Tools* -> *Visual Studio 2008 Command Prompt*), I get:

```
Setting environment for using Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 x86 tools.

C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE>
```

What kind of tools are available, and what are the most common uses of this command prompt?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

It basically just sets several of the Visual Studio binary locations into the `PATH` environment variable for that command window instance. This means you can use all the various commands and tools without having to include the full paths.

There's a partial list of some of the tools available on MSDN in *[.NET Framework Tools](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d9kh6s92.aspx)* and *[Tools (.NET Framework)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb400851.aspx)*.

Answer (score 11):

The Visual Studio command prompt is a convenient way to access the command line tools that ship with the [.NET Framework SDK](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Windows_SDK) and, if installed the, [Windows Platform SDK](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Windows_SDK) tools.

By providing the Visual Studio command prompt, Microsoft allows you to run these tools without requiring your PATH, INCLUDE, LIB and LIBPATH environment variables to contain all the additional paths to the various folders where Visual Studio and the .NET SDK are installed. Instead, these folder references are added on the fly when you start the Visual Studio command prompt allowing you to run the tools.

For example, if you open a regular command prompt you cannot run `xsd.exe` without changing to the directory `"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\SDK\v2.0\Bin"`. However, in the Visual Studio command prompt you can just type `xsd.exe /?`, and it works.

Please see the MSDN article *[.NET Framework Tools](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d9kh6s92.aspx)* for a complete list of the tools provided with Visual Studio 2008 SP1 and details on what they do.

Answer (score 1):

The Visual Studio command prompt has a few tools with it. Some tools are for repairing the install of Visual Studio. One of the tools I love using is for [WCF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Communication_Foundation). You type `wcftestclient` and you get a client to test your WCF services.

Comment: +1 for that!  I am about to start a project using a WCF service!

Answer (score 1):

The article *[The Visual Studio Command Prompt](https://web.archive.org/web/20170502062936/http://visualbasic.about.com:80/b/2010/08/17/the-visual-studio-command-prompt.htm)* has a nice explanation:

> Let's look at the "Visual Studio Command Prompt" in more detail.
>
> It appears to just set the path for you and put you in (Ta Da!) the VC
>   directory under Visual Studio. Not even the C# directory and certainly
>   not the VB directory. I guess they assume that anyone who uses this
>   tool is really hard core and programs directly against the hard drive
>   with a magnifying glass and a magnet.
>
> What it actually does is run this DOS command. (In my case.)
>
> %comspec% /k ""C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   10.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat"" x86
>
> What does vcvarsall.bat do? Well, it sets the target compiler
>   environment so you can compile code for a different processor.

Answer (score 0):

One use seems to be to call the XML Class Generator for using XSD schemas for serialization/deserialization:

[XML Class Generator for C# using XSD for deserialization](http://www.codingday.com/xml-c-class-generator-for-c-using-xsd-for-deserialization/)

Comment: xsd.exe is a slick tool, but it's not limited to the VS Command Prompt.  As Simon mentions the VS Command prompt just sets the Path environment variable to include locations of VS tools...  so you can just type "xsd.exe" instead of (something like) "c:\program files\microsfot visual studio 8.0\tools\bin\xsd.exe"

Answer (score 0):

## Simple example

After installing `Desktop development with C++` as part of the VS Installer, it installs `C++ CMake tools for Windows`. Let's run this `cmake.exe` file!

**VS Developer Command Prompt**

```
C:\Directory>cmake --version
cmake version 3.21.21080301-MSVC_2
```

**Windows Command Prompt**

```
C:\Directory>cmake --version
'cmake' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

## Why example behaves as it does

The VS Developer Command Prompt knew the command `cmake`, yet the Windows command prompt didn't.

Its almost as if it **is** and **isnt** a path variable - Schrodingers cat, errr path!

So where is `cmake.exe` that the VS developer command prompt says it knows about?

**VS Developer Command Prompt**

```
C:\Directory>where cmake
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\CMake\CMake\bin\cmake.exe
```

Okay so that means `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\CMake\CMake\bin\` must be a `PATH` variable.

Lets double check:

```
C:\Directory>set PATH
Path=C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\CMake\CMake\bin;
```

It is, great. Now why didnt the windows command prompt find it?

**Windows Command Prompt**

```
C:\Directory>set PATH
```

Hmmm, I'm looking at the list and its not there.

Now Simon Steven's and MikeD's answer can be put in context:

> It basically just sets several of the Visual Studio binary locations into the PATH environment variable for that command window instance. This means you can use all the various commands and tools without having to include the full paths.