# compiling C++ in windows cannot open file 'libcpmt.lib'

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, nmake

I am trying to compile libffm on my windows 10 machine:

```
https://github.com/guestwalk/libffm
```

I have Visual Studio Express 2013 installed and am using the `VS2013 x64 Cross Tools Command Prompt` to try and compile the package.

```
e:\libffm\nmake -f Makefile.win clean all

Microsoft (R) Program Maintenance Utility Version 12.00.21005.1
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

    erase /Q *.obj *.exe windows\.
    rd windows
    mkdir windows
    cl.exe /nologo /O2 /EHsc /D "_CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE" /D "USEOMP" /openmp -c ffm.cpp
ffm.cpp
ffm.cpp(1) : warning C4068: unknown pragma
    cl.exe /nologo /O2 /EHsc /D "_CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE" /D "USEOMP" /openmp ffm-train.cpp ffm.obj -Fewindows\ffm-train.exe
ffm-train.cpp
ffm-train.cpp(1) : warning C4068: unknown pragma
LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'libcpmt.lib'
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\BIN\x86_amd64\cl.exe"' : return code '0x2'
Stop.
```

I read that it maybe issues with my environment variables so have reinstalled the tools for C++ for VS2013 Express.

When I check the path variables I get:

```
echo %LIB%
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\LIB\amd64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\lib\winv6.3\um\x64;

echo %LIBPATH%
C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\LIB\amd64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\References\CommonConfiguration\Neutral;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.1\ExtensionSDKs\Microsoft.VCLibs\12.0\References\CommonConfiguration\neutral;
```

any ideas what to try next?

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18890801/link-fatal-error-lnk1104-cannot-open-file-libcpmt-lib-after-manually-config

Comment: ended up doing a full reinstall and it works now