# Setting Up .NET Build Environment with setenv - Two Warnings - Could not find vsvars32.bat Visual C++ Does not appear to be installed

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2012, gcc, msbuild, .net-micro-framework

I'm trying to compile some netmf firmware using MSBUILD with Yagarto. I'm doing it on a machine with VS2012 and all the right pre-requisites installed. From a command prompt as administrator, I go to the NetMF Porting Kit folder, where all the source code lives, I call setenv_gcc.cmd 4.6.0 c:\yagarto46

Doing so yields two warnings:

- WARNING: Count not find vsvars32.bat
- WARNING: VISUAL C++ DOES NOT APPEAR TO BE
  INSTALLED ON THIS MACHINE.

When I try the above command from VS2012 Developer Command Prompt as Administrator I get the following ERROR

- ERROR: Cannot determine the location of the VS Common Tools folder.

I've done the path modifications in Environment System Variables with no luck.

Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3461275/vs2010-command-prompt-gives-error-cannot-determine-the-location-of-the-vs-comm

This did the trick. I just adjusted for VS11.0(2012). I also updated the VS10.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[VS2010 command prompt gives error : Cannot determine the location of the VS Common Tools folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3461275/vs2010-command-prompt-gives-error-cannot-determine-the-location-of-the-vs-comm)

I modified the vsvars32.bat file in the vs11 and vs10 folders accordingly and the error went away... Now onto eliminating my build errors....