# Not able to run C:\\"Program Files\\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0"\\VC\\bin\\vcvars32.bat using Python

Tags: python, visual-studio-2010, python-2.7

While trying to automate a process I need to run C:\"Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0"\VC\bin\vcvars32.bat using the Python script. I tried it as below

```
p= subprocess.Popen('C:\\"Program Files\\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0"\\VC\\bin\\vcvars32.bat', shell=True,stdin=sub.PIPE,stdout=sub.PIPE, stderr=sub.STDOUT,)
```

but it throws an error as below:

Setting environment for using Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 x86 tools.

ERROR: Cannot determine the location of the VS Common Tools folder.

while on the contrary If I run the same command manually at the command prompt, it is a success.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3461275/vs2010-command-prompt-gives-error-cannot-determine-the-location-of-the-vs-comm

Comment: @Elisha but I am able to run the command manually, it just fails when I run it using the Python script.

Comment: according to the other Q i added, it can be PATH variable issue, what is the PATH value when you run with Popen?

Comment: Regarding `'C:\\"Program Files\\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0"\\VC\\bin\\vcvars32.bat'` Why are you using 2 different paren types?