# Metadata file .dll cannot be found CSC error

Tags: visual-studio-2013, compiler-errors, csc

I am getting CSC errors when trying to build my project. I have reference numerous threads here including this one on [metadata error dll not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1421862/metadata-file-dll-could-not-be-found).

I have checked build dependencies, unchecked and re-checked projects under Configuration Manager, checked environment variables for %VS120COMNTOOLS%, confirmed Path and C:\Windows\system32... I'm still getting a CSC error.

The error says that "Metadata file 'C:\Users\Username\Source\Workspaces\CompanyName\Main\CompanyDataModel\bin\Debug\CompanyDataModel.dll could not be found".

I've also looked and seen that I have a similar script as mentioned in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3461275/vs2010-command-prompt-gives-error-cannot-determine-the-location-of-the-vs-comm) in my .bat files. For example, the VCVarsQueryRegistry file has for loops like this:

```
@for /F "tokens=1,2*" %%i in ('reg query "%1\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.1" /v "InstallationFolder"') DO (
@if "%%i"=="InstallationFolder" (
    @SET "WindowsSdkDir=%%k"
)
```

)

Are these variables the problem? I tried to edit these for loops but right clicking and then Run as Administrator only brings up a blank command prompt and then it disappears. If I try to edit in Notepad, I get "Access denied" when I go to save the file.

What is causing these CSC errors?

Comment: I have gone in and changed the second variable in the code from an i to a j. I'm still getting the same metadata errors.

Answer (score 0):

As a last resort, I decided to download Visual Studio Ultimate 2013. (I was using Visual Studio Community 2013) After restarting Visual Studio Ultimate 2013, the metadata errors were still showing.

I then signed out of my Microsoft account and signed back in. I opened Visual Studio Ultimate 2013... and errors eliminated!