# SetEnv.cmd missing in Microsoft SDK

Tags: windows, winapi, sdk, windows-8.1

I have recently installed the Windows SDK but when I move to the the directory I can't find SetEnv.cmd. My OS is Windows 8.1, and the SDK is installed in Program Files (x86).

Comment: [Updated or removed features](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/bg162891): *The Windows SDK no longer ships with a complete command-line build environment. Instead, the Windows SDK requires a compiler and build environment to be installed separately.* Install [Visual Studio](https://www.visualstudio.com/vs-2015-product-editions).

Comment: After installation of VS, I in addition needed to manually add  ..\Windows\System32 to the PATH environment variable (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3461275/vs2010-command-prompt-gives-error-cannot-determine-the-location-of-the-vs-comm). After that, the build started all right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I found out is that I didn't have successfully installed the SDK after all. I had to remove all the distributables 2010 and try again. Also see this http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/101105-how-do-i-install-microsoft-windows-sdk-7-1

Answer (score 0):

I unistalled the Windows 8.1 SDK and then installed the Windows 7 SDK.

It contains the `SetEnv.cmd`.

Even Windows SDK works on Windows 10 as well.

Comment: I have installed Windows 7 SDK, but there isnt any `SetEnv.cmd`.

Comment: @YoushaAleayoub if you don't see any SetEnv.Cmd dont worry. What actually it do is to open the visual studio command prompt with administrator privileges. So you can do that manually and subsequently run your remaining configuration on that window.