# Can't open VS command prompt

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2012, command-prompt

I can't seem to start my Visual Studio 2012 command prompt.

Starting the command prompt, the window shows:

```
ERROR: Cannot determine the location of the VS Common Tools folder.

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0>msbuild
'msbuild' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0>
```

None of the tools seem to work (as shown by example of MSBuild).

I have already done my research which some of you seem to think that I haven't done. I have gone on to [VS2010 command prompt gives error : Cannot determine the location of the VS Common Tools folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3461275/vs2010-command-prompt-gives-error-cannot-determine-the-location-of-the-vs-comm) and the issue I had hasn't been solved.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VS2010 command prompt gives error : Cannot determine the location of the VS Common Tools folder](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3461275/vs2010-command-prompt-gives-error-cannot-determine-the-location-of-the-vs-comm)

Comment: Nope, I had already came across that and it didn't seem to solve my issue at all. :( And before you just down vote, why not find out if it is a legit question or not?

Comment: @DeanMarsden then you should have included that in your question and explained why it wasn't a dupe to avoid this getting closed as a duplicate

Comment: Downvotes are probably for not showing any research

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this very problem myself.

Problem was caused by registry access denied by domain group policy. I got around the problem by writing my own registry reading app and mangling the VS CMD starting bat file to use my own program.

I put my registry reader on git hub, you can check it out [here](https://github.com/geoffles/regread).

Instruction on how to apply the change on Git Hub.

Comment: Okay this totally solved my issue. Thanks a bunch :) This was way more constructive than the comments above.