# Resharper: "Property 'VS100COMNTOOLS' is not defined"

Tags: resharper

I get the above as an issue upon code inspection of an MSTest project. The issue relates to the .csproj itself.

What does it mean? Do I need to do anything about it ?

I know about the %VS100COMNTOOLS% environment variable, so I am guessing Resharper expects that path to be in the runtime environment of the project, and for some reason it's not ?

Comment: Did you ever resolve this issue? Got another report of it undefined @ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2990331/ms-c-2010-and-mspdb100-dll/2992862#comment18023679_2992862

Comment: Sorry, I don't even remembering asking this question :)