# Installing LuaFileSystem (lfs) on win7 x64

Tags: windows, lua, installation

I’m trying to install **LuaFileSystem** (lfs) on Windows 7 x64.
Tried it using Cygwin in a Linux style (using Make and config files), which gave me a lot of syntax errors.

Second try was using:

```
luarocks.bat install luafilesystem
```

Which I’m getting:

```
cl /MD /O2 -c -Fosrc/lfs.obj -IC:/Program Files (x86)/Lua/5.1/include src/lfs.c
'cl' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
Error: Build error: Failed compiling object src/lfs.obj
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\bin\cl.exe"
```

Trying to run using "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\bin\cl.exe" Throw:

```
"The program can't start because mspdb100.dll is missing from your computer"
```

Is there a simple way to install it on Windows 7 x64?
Thanks in advance,
Avi

Comment: What were the errors?

Comment: Added in the question.

Comment: Just a side remark, you can also try [Lua For Windows](http://code.google.com/p/luaforwindows/) compilation of all the tools/batteries for Lua.

Comment: Works without compiling, thanks everyone :).

Answer (score 0):

You need to fix Visual Studio.

There was a previous question here on SO about that:

[MS C++ 2010 and mspdb100.dll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2990331/ms-c-2010-and-mspdb100-dll)

First, check if the file is really missing, if it is, you can easily find a copy to put in your computer.

Later, you need to fix your PATH variable running this: path\to\VC\bin\vcvars32.bat

But read the post that I linked, it has more information and alternatives, try them all, one will work!