# Visual studio command prompt without installing visual studio

Tags: visual-studio-2008, command-prompt

is it possible to run visual studio command promt without installing visual studio?
i want to install regasm.exe from the vs command prompt as our server is 64bit.
And my requirement register using 32bit mode.

Comment: The VS command prompt just modifies the environment variables for that instance of the cmd. Take a look at this: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1125537/visual-studio-command-prompt-vs-regular-command-prompt

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`regasm.exe` is part of the .NET Framework installation, and thus not necessarily a part of Visual Studio.

Browse around in the directory `C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET` on your server. On an x64 machine, you will see the directory `C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework` where the 32-bit versions are kept, and `C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework64` for the 64-bit versions, natch.

You should see sub-folders inside those directories for the different .NET versions like `v2.0.50727`, `v3.0` and `v3.5`. `regasm.exe` can be found inside those folders. (Since .NET v3.0 and v3.5 build upon v2x.x, it's not in there, but can be found in v1.0x, v1.1x, and v2.0x.)

**Thus, the latest 32-bit version of regasm can be found at `C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\regasm.exe`, which you can run from any command prompt.**