# How do I convert Visual Studio .NET 2003 project build information to the VS command prompt?

Tags: .net, c++, c, visual-studio, compiler-construction

VS .NET 2003 C++ console application.

I would like to make a batch file that runs in the [VS command prompt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1125537/visual-studio-command-prompt-vs-regular-command-prompt) to compile just as if compiling from the VS IDE `build->rebuild solution` to create the .exe

I noticed under **project properties** `linker->command line` and `C\C++->command line` commands listed to compile and link from the command line. So I tried copying that information into a batch and ran under the VS environment but didn't really work.

Any help is appreciated.

Thank You.

**EDIT**
sorry, in case I did not communicate properly. I would like this batch file to contain all the switches and list the .cpp files and objects to create, so that the VS project is not needed, just the environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you upgrade to 2005, you can use `vcbuild`. If you upgrade to 2010, you can use `msbuild`. For 2003, your only option is [`devenv /build`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b20w810z%28v=VS.71%29.aspx).